# How to get Monthly view in Outlook Web Access in Firefox 4.0?

Tags: firefox, calendar, outlook-on-the-web

Using Microsoft Office Outlook Web Access **in Firefox 4.0** to work with my calendar, I'm only able to get one day up at a time, with a small monthly calendar on the side.  In Internet Explorer it lets me log in choosing either Premium or Basic version, and Premium gives me the monthly options.  Firefox doesn't give me those two options, and just logs me in as Basic.

How do I change the main view to monthly so I can view my whole month and the appointments in it, OR how can I get Firefox to let me log in as Premium?

[image: OWA Basic]

**End Result**:  I used the [User Agent Switcher Add-On](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) in Firefox to fake being IE, and while it let me sign in for a Premium session, it didn't function at all.  So for now the answer is that OWA Premium does not support Firefox.  I'll update this question if I see it change in the future.

**Update**:  I'm now using Firefox 25 and the Web Access Version I'm using is 14.2.342.3 and I have the monthly view, so at some point the version changes allowed it to work right.

Comment: Have you tried using a plugin to adjust your UserAgent string to IE for the OWA site?  I suspect it will attempt to work but the 2007 version of premium OWA was very buggy with FF3.6.  I haven't tried 4.0.

Comment: @Zoredache, ok, I tried that, and found that Premium didn't function at all in FF 4.0, so I guess that's my answer for now.  I'll have to update this question in the future if I see anything change.

Answer (score 1):

There are different versions of OWA floating around but the current version, Outlook Web App (formerly Outlook Web Access) has icons at the top to switch views.
I cannot remember how it was done in earlier versions.

[image: Monthly View for OWA]

Comment: Mine still says Web Access, the version # is 8.3.137.0, and there is a 2007 copyright.  I've added a pic.

Comment: @Lance yeah I am not really sure where to find features by version number. The closest answer to this that I saw was that the monthly view was added in SP1 for the 2007 Exchange Server but only the premium version of OWA. It seems during Beta, they did not have time to get it in as a feature.

Sources: http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2006/05/12/3394012.aspx#3394029 and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676323(EXCHG.80).aspx

Comment: OK, you gave me a clue.  I've now found that in IE I get the Premium/Basic choice.  I've always chosen premium and had the monthly option.  It appears that FF 4.0 isn't giving me that choice, so I get basic.  So I'll edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be something that only works properly in the "Premium" version of the Outlook Web Access interface.

Pre-Exchange 2010 the only web browser supported for OWA Premium is Internet Explorer 6+ on Windows, they don't code for or test with any other browser and the code uses IE specific code that doesn't work with other browsers.

[Outlook Web App supports a much wider variety of browsers](http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/bb899685%28EXCHSRVCS.140%29.aspx) for its Premium mode, but is part of Exchange 2010:

> To use the complete set of features
>   available in Outlook Web App and the
>   Exchange Control Panel, you can use
>   the following browsers on a computer
>   running Windows XP, Windows 2003,
>   Windows Vista, or Windows 7:
>
> - Internet Explorer 7 and later versions.
> - Firefox 3.0.1 and later versions.
> - Chrome 3.0.195.27 and later versions.
>
> On a computer running Mac OS X 10.5
>   and later versions, you can use:
>
> - Safari 3.1 and later versions.
> - Firefox 3.0.1 and later versions.
>
> On a computer running Linux, you can
>   use:
>
> - Firefox 3.0.1 and later versions.
>
> If you use a Web browser that doesn't
>   support the full feature set, Outlook
>   Web App will open in the light
>   version.

Answer (score 1):

When I log into the Outlook Web Access (OWA) on Firefox , there is a ticked box which sets 'Light' as the client type, which has way less icons and features than the full client.
However, when I use Internet Explorer, I get the full client.  Reading the front screen more carefully, it does say that other browsers default to the light client.  Microsoft tying you into IE ...?